# Grading long text answer in edX based on keywords

Tags: javascript, python, regex, openedx, edx

I want to construct a problem in edX, in which student answers with several sentences, and gets a grade based on several keywords.
E.g. with [Python-evaluated (write-your-own-grader) problem](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-partner-course-staff/en/latest/exercises_tools/custom_python.html#create-a-custom-python-evaluated-input-problem-in-studio).  I would describe it like that:

```
<problem> 
<customresponse cfn="test_keywords">
<script type="loncapa/python">
```

```py
def test_keywords(expect,ans):
  keywords=[u'foo', u'bar',u'baz']
  answer=ans.lower()
  keywords_number=len(keywords)
  keyword_counter=0
  result=0
  for keyword in keywords:
    if type(keyword)==str:
      if keyword in answer:
        print (keyword)
        keyword_counter+=1
        continue
    else:
      for synonym in keyword:
        if synonym in answer: keyword_counter+=1
        print(synonym)
        break
  print (keyword_counter)
  result=int(keyword_counter/keywords_number*100)
  print (result)
  if result>0:
    return {'input_list': [{ 'ok': True, 'msg': 'Your score is ' + str(result) + '%','grade_decimal':result/100},]}
  else: return False
```

```
</script>
  <label>Enter your answer</label>
  <textline size="40" correct_answer="foo123 bar456 baz789" label="input:" /><br/>



    <solution>
          <div class="detailed-solution">
              <p>Blah</p>

          </div>
      </solution>
  </customresponse>
</problem>
```

There are other ways to do that:

1. [Regex in Text Input problem](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-partner-course-staff/en/latest/exercises_tools/text_input.html#allowing-regular-expressions-as-answers-for-text-input-problems). Not much information about it in official docs. If I'm getting the idea right, I will need to define all variations of keywords order. Text input field is small.
2. [xblock-free-text-response](https://github.com/Stanford-Online/xblock-free-text-response) , looks like [that](https://edx-code.narkive.com/svCNRLYk/problem-type-that-allows-ungraded-text-answers:i.6.1.full) . Text input seems to be big enough.

Would appreciate any comments on ways of solving this, or maybe there is a better one.
At the moment I'm using edX in SaaS cloud, if it matters.

**Strangely the code above returns right score in Google Colab notebook, but in edX results are weird (100% or 66% for 1 of 3 keywords). I have no idea, how can it happen, and how can I debug this?**

Answer (score 1):

seems your code is for python3, but you run it on python2, so code should be like

```
def test_keywords(expect,ans):
  keywords=[u'foo', u'bar',u'baz']
  answer=ans.lower()
  keywords_number=len(keywords)
  print ('keywords_number', keywords_number);
  keyword_counter=0
  result=0
  for keyword in keywords:
    print ('keyword', keyword)
    print ('keyword type', type(keyword));
    if type(keyword) == unicode:
      if keyword in answer:
        print ('keyword in answer', keyword)
        keyword_counter+=1
        continue
    else:
      for synonym in keyword:
        print('synonym', synonym)
        if synonym in answer: keyword_counter+=1
        print('synonym in answer', synonym)
        break
  print ('keyword counter', keyword_counter)
  result=int((1.0*keyword_counter/(1.0*keywords_number)*100))
  print (result)
  if result>0:
    return {'input_list': [{ 'ok': True, 'msg': 'Your score is ' + str(result) + '%','grade_decimal':result/100},]}
  else: return False
```

please note, I add strings to debug prints, so it will be easer to understand debug prints

Answer (score 0):

Finally this works for me:

```py
def test_keywords(expect,ans):
  keywords=[u'foo', u'bar',[u'baz',u'boo']]
  answer=ans.lower()
  keywords_number=len(keywords)
  keyword_counter=0
  result=0
  
  for keyword in keywords:
  
    if type(keyword)!=list:
      if keyword in answer:
        keyword_counter+=1
        continue
  
    else:
      for synonym in keyword:
        if synonym in answer:
            keyword_counter+=1
            break

  result=int(keyword_counter/keywords_number*100)
  if result>0:
    return {'input_list': [{ 'ok': True, 'msg': 'Your score is ' + str(result) + '%','grade_decimal':result/100}]}
  else: return False
```